# Tasker: Task after receiving email

Tags: tasker

Can I initaite any task in *tasker app* if i receive  **email** from specific id with particular subject like we do in case of sms.

Comment: An E-Mail is working totally different than an SMS: The SMS is received by Android and then delivered to the selected App, therefore receieving new SMS is easy. However new E-Mails are checked, received and processed by your E-Mail app. They never leave the E-Mail app. How should tasker get access to the E-Mail?

Comment: If the email shows up as a notification, you can use AutoNotification app to detect it and run a task. Otherwise, I see no other way.

Comment: There's also a 'k9 email received' event you can use to initiate the task.